# Appcelerator Alloy TableView click event is not firing up on parent tableview

Tags: titanium, tableview, appcelerator

Im building a app that i have a tableview inside a tableview row.

i have a click event in the main tableview, that i wish to keep.

```
 <Alloy>

<Collection src="orders" />
<Window onAndroidback="closeWindow" id="activeorderswindow" class="maincontainer_noactionbar">
    <View class="topcontainer">
        <ImageView class="topbackbutton" onClick="closeWindow"></ImageView>
        <Label class="topheadinglabel">Aktive ordre</Label>
        <ImageView class="topmenubutton" onClick="closeWindow"></ImageView>
    </View>

    <View class="maindatacontainer">
        <TableView class="orderstable" id="activeorderstable" dataTransform="transformFunction" dataCollection="orders" dataFunction="updateUI" onDragEnd="refreshTable" >
        <!-- Also can use Require -->
            <TableViewRow class="activeordersrow" oid="{oid}" touchEnabled="true" >
                <Label class="rowOid" text="{oid}"/>
                <Label class="rowCust" text="{cust}"/>
                <Label class="rowScode" text="{scode}"/>
                <Label class="rowVehicle" text="{vehicle}"/>
                <Label class="rowOrdertime" text="{ordertime}"/>
                <ImageView class="imgOrdertime" image='/images/clock_green.png'/>
                <ImageView class="imgDeadline" image='/images/clock_red.png'/>
                <Label class="rowDeadline" text="{deadline}"/>
                <View class="addresstablewrapper" backgroundColor="#000"/>
                <TableView touchEnabled="false" scrollType="vertical" class="activeorders_addresses" data="{orders_addresses}" backgroundColor="yellow" />
            </TableViewRow>
        </TableView>    
    </View>
</Window>
```

The problem is that because i have another within the table  with its own rows (without a click event) it seems like the click on the main does not fire.

Help appreciated :)

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I have rarely seen such patterns of including a tableview inside another tableview.

Comment: Why are you nesting tableviews, may be you are looking for implementing sections ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the nested TableView should have touchEnabled="true" so the click bubbles up to the parent (tableviewrow).